# MUI KeyboardDatePicker

Tags: javascript, css, material-ui

I have mui [keyboardDatePicker](https://material-ui-pickers.dev/api/KeyboardDatePicker) component in a project  and have the `InputAdornmentProps={{ position: 'start', variant: 'standard' }}` prop in use to move the icon from end to start of the field.

[image: picture of component]

This leaves a space at the end for an endAdornment, i.e. a tick / cross icon for success / fail validation... so how do i get one there? InputAdornmentProps handles the calendar icon, how do I add another icon into this component - is it possible? I don't see a prop that will allow this?

Comment: It appears you are using MUIv4 if you're using the Material-UI Pickers.  Correct?  I only ask because date pickers were moved into the library in v5 and may have a slightly different answer to your question.

Comment: Yes, the old KeyboardDatePicker, i added a link to the component above. There is some tech debt to do before we update to mui 5 hence i can't use that currently.